# How to decrease the font size of a table in an \input file

Tags: tables, fontsize, external-files

I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This is the main tex document.
\input{tables}
\end{document}
```

In the `tables.tex` file, I only have numerical tables.  I want to decrease the size of fonts used in the table, without modifying `tables.tex`.  Is there proper commands that I can enter right before `\input{tables}`?

FYI, `tables.tex` looks like:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{table caption}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
$u$   & 0.00  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the font size of the `tabular` *only*, or also that of the caption?

Comment: @Werner `tabular` only, but either is okay.

Comment: The title here is actually misleading. Font changes have nothing to do if the content is in a `\input` file or not. Your issue here is that the `table` environment changes the font itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
{\renewcommand\normalsize{\tiny}%
\normalsize
\input{tables}}
```

Comment: This does not work for my files. I added more details.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  Corrected.

Comment: You don't need to keep wrong answers around. Old versions of all post can anyway be viewed. Simply remove and update any incorrect things.

Comment: @martin-sharrer  Wrong answers actually might be useful to show the traps, but just for brevity I've deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to tap into the start of the `tabular` environment and modify the font size. In the MWE below, the `tabular` font size is set to `\Huge`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\Huge}% Adjust tabular font size to \Huge

\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{table caption}
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    $u$ & 0.00  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Here is some dummy text.

\input{table}%

Here is some more dummy text.
\end{document}
```

As the name states, `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{<env>}{<stuff>}` command inserts `<stuff>` before the beginning of the environment `<env>` - `tabular` in this case.

---

If you're interested in modifying only the tables that are included using `\input`, then it would be best to define your own `\input` command, say `\myinput`, and combine it with @Boris' answer. Here's an example of how to do just that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{A table included via \texttt{input}}
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    $u$ & 0.00  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\myinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand\normalsize{\tiny}% Specify your font modification
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
Here is some dummy text.

\myinput{table}%

Here is some more dummy text.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{A table in the main document}
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    $u$ & 0.00  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Grouping within the `\myinput{<file>}` command (using `\begingroup...\endgroup`) ensures that the `\normalsize` redefinition remains local.

Comment: This works good for me. Just for the future use, would it be possible to impact only the tabular's in the `tables.tex` file? I want all other tables in the main tex file normal, but only tables in the external file tiny (or huge).

Comment: @Chang: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the following example I define a new command `\CFTable` with one optional argument, which redefines the `table` and `table*` environments as defined by the standard document classes; the optional argument will select the font size switch to be applied to the tables (it will not have any effect on the captions); the valid values for the optional argument are `tiny`, `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small` (default), `normalsize`, `large`, `Large`, `LARGE`, `huge`, and `Huge`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testtables.tex}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Some test table}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  text & text \\
  123 & 234\\
  123 & 234\\
  123 & 234\\
  123 & 234\\
  123 & 234\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CTFont[1][small]{
\renewenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}\csname#1\endcsname}
               {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}\csname#1\endcsname}
               {\end@dblfloat}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\CTFont% tables in \small size
\input{testtables}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\CTFont[tiny]% tables in \tiny size
\input{testtables}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\CTFont[Large]% tables in \Large size
\input{testtables}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `filecontents` package and the `filecontents*` environment are only to provide a complete compilable example; you don't need them in your actual code.

With the code above, the change in the font size will only affect the table contents but not the captions; to achieve a simultaneous change to the caption font size, it's enough to load the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

and change the definition of `\CFTable` to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\CTFont[1][small]{
\captionsetup[table]{font=#1}
\renewenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}\csname#1\endcsname}
               {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}\csname#1\endcsname}
               {\end@dblfloat}
}
\makeatother
```

now, however, the only valid values for the optional argument are `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small` (default), `normalsize`, `large`, and  `Large`.

Comment: Both methods do not work for my files. I added more details.

Comment: @Chang: I've updated my answer according to the new information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention by how much you want to reduce the font's size. Latex gives you four choices -- `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny` -- to reduce the font size below `\normalsize`.  I'll assume that, for the sake of argument, you're looking to employ the size `\small`, which is generally 1pt smaller than `\normalsize`.

If you place the following code snippet in your document's preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}%
    \renewcommand\normalsize{\small} % or \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \tiny, as needed
    \@float{table}}
    {\end@float}
\makeatother
```

no further changes to your code should be necessary. Note that the meaning of `\normalsize` will be unchanged outside of `table` environments.

If you want the fontsize-changing command to affect only tables in the `tables.tex` file, but no other tables, you could just insert the command

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{\small} % or \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \tiny, as needed
```

immediately before the `\input tables` instruction. (Your MWE seems to indicate that these tables are at the end of the document, so there's no need to encase the statements in a pair of braces.)

Comment: don't forget `\scriptsize`.

Comment: This does not work for my files. I added more details.

Comment: @Chang: Please add some information: do you get an error message, a warning message? Which font family are you using?

Comment: @Mico I exactly used the codes in my question. I do not get any error/warning message. It simply does not change the font size of the table.

Comment: @Chang: have you tried `\include{tables.tex}` instead of `\input`?

Comment: @Mico `\include` also does not work.

Comment: @Mico: the problem with your answer (in fact, with Boris's and mine too before we corrected them after the edit to the original question) is that the `table` environment changes internally the font size.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- thanks! I'll change my answer, providing a solution not yet mentioned. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
\renewcommand\normalsize{
  \fontsize{10pt}{17pt}\selectfont}
  \normalsize\input{your-table-or-file}
}
```

define size and spacing using the `\fontsize{10pt}{17pt}`.

Works with pdflatex, not sure about XeLatex and others.